# Import node package from node_modules subdirectory

Tags: npm, node-modules, package.json

Let’s say we have a package named “mypackage” that we own. We also use this package in another project: “my-client”. Once installed, “my-package” is saved inside the node_modules directory of “my-client”.

There’s a specific file inside this “my-package” that I want to import in “my-client”. Let’s say the path to this file is: “node_modules/mypackage/dist/components/my-component.js”

I know that I can import this file as follows: 
`import myComponent from ‘mypackage/dist/components/my-component’`

However, for a better dev experience, I want to be able to just say:
`import myComponent from ‘mypackage/my-component’`

I feel like this could be achieved by some package.json magic inside “my-package” but I can’t figure out how to do it.

Things I tried:

- Setting the “main” key to “dist/components/index.js”
- Setting the “module” key to “dist/components/index.js”

Comment: I've wasted hours and hours trying to do the same and failed miserably. As far as I can see, this is not doable as of 26th April 2019 haha